# how to inactive local notification between start date and end date in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

1. I want to stop local notification between start date till end date.
2. Here is the piece of code which i have written for daily local notification:

   ```
   UILocalNotification *localNotif11 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
   localNotif11.alertBody = @"Hello";
   localNotif11.alertTitle=@"Reminder";
   localNotif11.soundName=@"notification.caf";
   NSDateComponents *components11 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]   components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth)   fromDate:[NSDate date]];
   [components11 setHour:11];
   [components11 setMinute:00];
   localNotif11.fireDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]   dateFromComponents:components11];
   localNotif11.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

   NSLog(@"%@",localNotif11.fireDate);
   [localNotif11 setRepeatInterval:NSCalendarUnitDay];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif11];
   ```

Comment: you can't pause/stop `UILocalNotification`. so you should cancel and create schedule new `UILocalNotification`

Comment: You can set an unique value for key in your local notification's userinfo. Then Get all your local notification, loop through the array and delete the particular notification.

Comment: can you please share sample code.if user wants to go on vacation he will select start date and end date.Between this dates we don't want send notification

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:7];
notification.alertBody = @"This is local notification!";
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 10;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

UILocalNotification *notification1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification1.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:8];
notification1.alertBody = @"This is local notification!";
notification1.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notification1.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notification1.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 10;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification1];

NSArray *arr = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];

for (UILocalNotification *notif in arr) {
    NSLog(@"Local:: %@",notif.fireDate);
}
```

you are check firedate in present your till date.

Comment: I don't  want to remove notification i just want to stop notification when user selects start date and end date for vacation.

Comment: but i want to stop notification after some date

Comment: you are check firedate is include in start date and end date. Is include that write code: 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];